# DirectX11 Map / Unmap Runtime Error

Tags: c++, directx, shader, directx-11

Whenever I use the map / unmap functions per frame my program errors with the warning

"Unhandled exception at 0x0F285A07 (atidxx32.dll) in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

after about 20 seconds.

On the line `result = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTargetTexture);`

I believe this is because of the renderTargetTexture not being accessible in some way.

I set the texture in the following way at initialisation and then every frame. The program works fine if I do not update every frame but I need to do this to pass arrays to the GPU.

¬Setup Texture Description

¬¬Code breaks on last line of setting texture (CreateTexture2D). Seems to be the render target.

¬Map and Unmap the texture

¬Set the shader resource

---

Setting up the texture

```
bool setupTextureDesc(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC& textureDesc)
{
    HRESULT result;
    // Initialize the render target texture description.
    ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));

    // Setup the render target texture description.
    textureDesc.Width = fluidBufferObj.width;
    textureDesc.Height = fluidBufferObj.height;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    // Create the render target texture.
    result = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTargetTexture);
    HRFAIL
}
```

Map and Unmap

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    //Map the resources. Blocks the GPU from accessing the file. 
    result = deviceContext->Map(renderTargetTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    HRFAIL
    //Set the pixels
    UCHAR* pTexels = (UCHAR*)mappedResource.pData;
    //For 3D do the same but add "depthStart" as mappedResource.DepthPitch * depth

    int startIndex = (float)( ((float)percentage / 100) * (float)textureDesc.Height );

    for( UINT row = 0; row < textureDesc.Height; row++ )
    {
        //Row number * height
        UINT rowStart = row * mappedResource.RowPitch;
        for( UINT col = 0; col < textureDesc.Width; col++ )
        {
            if( row >= startIndex && row <= (startIndex + 10) )
            {
                //width * number of channels (r,g,b,a)
                UINT colStart = col * 4;
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = 0; // Red
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = 0; // Green
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = 255; // Blue
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = 255; // Alpha
            }
            else
            {
                //width * number of channels (r,g,b,a)
                UINT colStart = col * 4;
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = 255; // Red
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = 0; // Green
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = 0; // Blue
                pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = 255; // Alpha
            }
        }
    }
    //Free the resource
    deviceContext->Unmap(renderTargetTexture, 0);
```

Setting render target

```
bool setupTextureDesc(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC& textureDesc)
{
    HRESULT result;
    // Initialize the render target texture description.
    ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));

    // Setup the render target texture description.
    textureDesc.Width = fluidBufferObj.width;
    textureDesc.Height = fluidBufferObj.height;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    // Create the render target texture.
    result = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTargetTexture);
    HRFAIL
}
```

Comment: **Kill FRAPS! :)** It's my first advice for any DX issue.

Comment: Not using FRAPS, I assume you mean the screen recording software?

Comment: Access violation reading location 0x00000000, this is because you are reading an pointer point to NULL, it seems renderTargetTexture was not correctly initialized. but you didn't paste enough code.

Comment: The render target is initialised fine as it crashes after 20 seconds, unless it fails to initialise from the previous frame.

Comment: It is not failing to be reinitialised. I suspect it is being caught by the GPU or something strange but I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Is this all running in the same thread?

Comment: @Dino (1) **Use debugger!** When exception will be thrown again, let it set a breakpoint. Watch values of variables. Find null pointer being dereferenced. Walk call stack if needed to find where pointer was invalidated.  (2) **Enable [DirectX Debug Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** and watch output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Drop I used the assert function assert( variable != NULL ) and all of them passed, still got the error.

Comment: @RogerRowland same thread, yes, which makes me question how it could be getting hung up.

Comment: @Drop When I enable the debug flag the method ClearRenderTarget gives me the error Unhandled exception at 0x76D3C41F (KernelBase.dll). I commented it out to see what the output was for the RT error but the only extra information is telling me that an RT is not being passed to the pixel shader. As well as Unhandled exception at 0x0FCC5A07 (atidxx32.dll) in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the error was but I seem to have fixed it by eliminating the setting up texture description and setting shader resource steps.

The every frame code is simply mapping and unmapping the texture now, seems the others were...unnecessary.

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
//Map the resources. Blocks the GPU from accessing the file. 
result = deviceContext->Map(renderTargetTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0,             &mappedResource);
HRFAIL

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC* tDesc = new D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC();
renderTargetTexture->GetDesc(tDesc);

//Set the pixels
UCHAR* pTexels = (UCHAR*)mappedResource.pData;
//For 3D do the same but add "depthStart" as mappedResource.DepthPitch * depth

int startIndex = (float)( ((float)percentage / 100) * (float)tDesc->Height );

for( UINT row = 0; row < tDesc->Height; row++ )
{
    //Row number * height
    UINT rowStart = row * mappedResource.RowPitch;
    for( UINT col = 0; col < tDesc->Width; col++ )
    {
        if( row >= startIndex && row <= (startIndex + 10) )
        {
            //width * number of channels (r,g,b,a)
            UINT colStart = col * 4;
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = 0; // Red
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = 0; // Green
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = 255; // Blue
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = 255; // Alpha
        }
        else
        {
            //width * number of channels (r,g,b,a)
            UINT colStart = col * 4;
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 0] = 255; // Red
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 1] = 0; // Green
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 2] = 0; // Blue
            pTexels[rowStart + colStart + 3] = 255; // Alpha
        }
    }
}
//Free the resource
deviceContext->Unmap(renderTargetTexture, 0);
```